# access const in different class from aspx page

Tags: asp.net, .net

How can I access a const in a module from an aspx page?

I use this to access const in the code behind:

```
<%=MY_CONST%>
```

What is the difference when the Const is in a different class (a module in the project)?

**First edit:**
So I tried the solutions "use <%= Myclass.Myconst %>" but I got the error "Name Myclass is not declared".

Here is more details:
The class is in the same project.
It is a module wich contains multiple Const.
I use VB.net
.NET 3.5

any ideas?

**Solution**:

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960602/how-do-i-access-a-module-or-a-public-class-with-public-shared-members-from-inlin) :

I need to add an import statement:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Mynamespace.Myclass" %>
```

and then I can use:

```
<%=MyConst%>
```

Comment: Your const is probably attached to a class, so you can use something like `MyClass.MY_CONST`

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Class TheClass
    Public Const MY_CONST As String = "123456"
End Class
```

You can access it like:

```
<%=TheClass.MY_CONST%>
```

If you are using c# make sure the class is in the same `namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the constant value is a `public` value and reference it like this:

```
<%= YourClassName.MY_CONST %>
```